# PyCharm 3.10 CE Run Tool Pane No Longer Displaying Colors, Has Large Cursor

Tags: pycharm

Novice Python programmer here completing my first Python certification, so please bear with me.

Had been using PyCharm CE 3.10 with no issues, but recently after adding a .txt file to my code, the Run Tool pane is no longer displaying colors and now has a HUGE cursor.

I have scoured Stack and the PyCharm resources, but to no avail - all of those directed to Settings, which are unchanged from default.

For testing, I created a second Python file including the addition of a .txt file, and the Run Tool colors and cursor remained intact, leading me to believe there is something in my code triggering the color issue.

Is there something in my code that is triggering this issue with the Run Tool pane, or is it a bug with PyCharm? Thank you in advance for your help!

(Stack will not yet let me post images, so apologies for no screenshot)